# Как коротко записать правило о наращении падежного окончания порядковых числительных?

Tags: стилистика, сокращения, правила

**[**Вот вариант справочной службы** о правиле сокращений:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87)**

*По закрепившейся традиции наращение должно быть **однобуквенным**, если **последней** букве числительного предшествует **гласный** звук: 5-й день (пятый день), 25-я годовщина (двадцать пятая годовщина), в 32-м издании (в тридцать втором издании), в 14-м ряду (в четырнадцатом ряду).*

*Наращение должно быть **двухбуквенным**, если последней букве предшествует **согласный**: 5-го дня (пятого дня), к 25-му студенту (к двадцать пятому студенту), из 32-го издания (из тридцать второго издания), из 14-го ряда (из четырнадцатого ряда).*

**Информации здесь немного, но как много слов!** Стоит задуматься об информативности сообщения.  Есть **парные** слова, которые нужно комбинировать: наращение однобуквенное и двухбуквенное, согласный и гласный звуки. Есть и **другие** слова, которые требуют внимания: предшествует, последней букве.

Можно ли как-то упростить запись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, формулировка рекомендации, данная **справочной службой** далека от совершенства. Если ее "избавить от словесных излишеств", то она становится не только короче, но и проще для восприятия. Например:

Запись порядковых числительных арабскими цифрами  дополняют **однобуквенным** наращением: 5-е действие, в 2001-м году, но если последней букве предшествует согласный, то наращение должно быть **двухбуквенным**: с 2001-го (первого) года, к 25-му (пятому) числу.

В этом виде запись рекомендации справочной службы содержит 252 знака (с учетом пробелов), что примерно соответствует «статистке» по записи формулировки, опирающейся на «окончание числительного».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  У меня такой вопрос: имеет ли упрощенное правило, которое я предлагаю, какие-нибудь ограничения? Всегда ли можно им пользоваться?

Comment: Грамота приводит больше примеров (и это хорошо), пишет их и цифрами, и словами. Отсюда много текста. Если же убрать примеры, пробелы и знаки, то совсем ненамного больше её формулировка: 180 букв (у Вас 151), а если убрать начальное "По закрепившейся традиции", то и того меньше – 157. Почти сравнялись.

Comment: Александр, а зачем знаки-то считать. Я говорю о сложности восприятия текста при начальном изучении правила. Вы его выучили, и вам оно нравится. А я начала учить, а СМЫСЛ понять не могу. Так, думаю, если смысла нет, то можно придумать другую формулировку.

Comment: Совы слетелись клевать мое правило, да?))  Как-то поздно уж, вчера надо было.

Comment: @Sharon, автор ответа говорит о количестве, краткости, поэтому я отметил, что его формулировка не очень отличается в этом плане. // О совершенстве и о том, что оно мне нравится, я не пишу. А ваш вопрос и ваше правило я отметил плюсами ещё вчера.

Comment: Я уже не могу понять, откуда негатив, кому я помешала со своим правилом. Предчувствие...."Попробую задать на эту тему вопрос — посмотрим на реакцию участников, очень любопытно! Вероятно, новаторство никому не понравится, но все-таки интересно".  А.С.Пушкин: Снова тучи надо мною
Собралися в тишине;
Рок завистливый бедою
Угрожает снова мне...

Comment: @Sharon  Ещё раз: "А ваш вопрос и ваше правило я отметил плюсами ещё вчера". Где вы видите негатив?

Comment: Извините, я  не вас имею в виду, я просто не могу понять, кто как настроен. Нет атмосферы доброжелательного отношения... "Правило" не всем нравится, меня никто не похвалил, а вся критика с негативным подтекстом,  Нет существенных замечаний, а эмоций много.

Comment: Ваш вариант почти не отличается от варианта справочной службы. Разве что вступление отсутствует. Грамота.ру ответила предельно четко и ясно.

Answer (score 3):

**Вот мое правило**:

При записи порядковых числительных  с помощью арабских цифр к числу добавляется **окончание числительного**, сокращенное  на **одну букву**,  например:

перв/ый ряд — **1-й ряд**,  из перв/ого ряда  —  **из  1-го ряда**,  к перв/ому ряду — **к 1-му ряду**,  в перв/ом ряду — **в 1-м ряду**.

**Примечание.**  Обратим внимание на слово ***третий.***  Здесь окончание **нулевое** (*ИЙ* — это суффикс). Но тогда можно считать, что числительное оканчивается на *ИЙ*, результат получим тот же: ***3-й класс***. Или сокращаем  числительное по обычному правилу (после гласного): ***3-й класс***.

Comment: Может, просто людям трудно определить окончание?

Comment: Я думаю, что это не труднее, чем понять  текст у Грамоты. Ведь особого смысла в этом решении нет (оно делается по традиции), а формулировка НАУКООБРАЗНАЯ, что можно определить по специальной терминологии. Нужно прочитать эту фразу несколько раз, чтобы понять ее смысл. А смысл-то ПРОСТЕЙШИЙ!  Я понимаю, что однажды прочитав правило и поняв-таки его содержание, пользователи (которым просто необходимо быть грамотными) переходят на СОГЛАСНЫЕ И ГЛАСНЫЕ буквы. (Другие же так и не знают это правило.)

Comment: Но вот что надо отметить: всем пользователя придется различать согласные и гласные буквы, а это тоже очень трудно))  Так что выбираем, что кому труднее.

Comment: Это отнюдь-ничуть не трудно.

Comment: Sharon:  «_**Или сокращаем числительное по обычному правилу (после гласного): 3-й**_». === То есть, получается, что в дополнение к Вашему правилу нужно знать ещё и обычное, которое Вы критиковали за  то, что в нём «**как много слов!**».

Comment: Тогда я оставлю только оканчивается на ИЙ, так пойдет?

Comment: Пишете: "вся критика с негативным подтекстом". Критики было совсем чуть-чуть от одного отвечающего, негатива не почувствовал. // Сейчас мне не очень нравится дополнение в виде примечания: какое-то оно не чёткое, последнее предложение, по-моему, не нужно. // А ещё интересно насчёт суффикса. Вроде бы спорный вопрос (где-то говорят об оконании -ИЙ). В им. падеже нет окончания, но оно появляется при склонении?

Comment: По-моему, не пойдёт. Но это только моё мнение, трём другим пользователям оно, похоже, очень понравилось.

Comment: Тогда оставляем, не будем расстраивать сразу троих.  Обычно исключения подтверждают правила, а третий – исключение.

Answer (score 2):

> **Вот вариант справочной службы** о правиле сокращений…
>
> Наращение падежного окончания в порядковых числительных, обозначенных
> арабскими цифрами…  **должно быть двухбуквенным, если последней букве
> предшествует согласный…**
>
> **Информации здесь немного, но как много слов!..**
>
> Можно ли как-то упростить запись?

**Можно и упростить, если выкинуть все примеры. Но нужно ли это делать?**

Другое дело, что оно не даёт ответа на то, как следует записать в числовой форме с наращением числительные ***третье, третья, третью***. В этих словах последней букве предшествует согласный мягкий «т’», и потому, если следовать формулировке правила, запись данных числительных в числовой форме должна была бы быть такой: «3-ье», «3-ья», «3-ью», что некоторые и делают.

**Я бы заменил в правиле ссылку на звуки перед последней буквой числительного ссылкой на буквы:**

> По закрепившейся традиции наращение должно быть **однобуквенным**,
> если **последней букве** числительного предшествует **гласная или
> мягкий знак**: *5-й день (пятый день), 3-е издание (третье издание)*.
>
> Наращение должно быть **двухбуквенным**, если последней букве
> предшествует **согласная**: *5-го дня (пятого дня).*

**P.S.**

Хочу обратить внимание обсуждающих этот вопрос на то, что в словах ***третье, третья, третью*** окончание **однобуквенное**, и потому воспользоваться для этих числительных правилом, предложенным автором вопроса (сократить на одну букву окончание при записи в числовой форме) просто никак не получится.

Comment: Примеры не важны, рассматриваем только текст.  Вы можете ориентироваться на гласные и согласные,  но я предлагаю просто сократить количество букв  в окончании. Выбирайте!

Comment: Sharon, я дополнил свой ответ, пояснив, почему не согласен с предложенным Вами правилом.

Comment: Мы еще вчера обсуждали эту тему с буквами (с другим участником). Вот запись:  Очень просто! Смотрю на окончание – сколько буковок (одна, две. три). Одну не сократишь, а от двух и трех можно по единичке отнять. Вот и получаем: 1-е, 2-е, 1-го, 2-го. Как вам? Критика нужна! Я нашим рассказывала, но они ничего не поняли и слушать не стали.

Comment: Не согласны – не пользуйтесь. What problems?

Comment: Но нам же нужно правило не только для записи слов **первое, первого, второе, второго…**». Для этих слов Ваше правило подходит. Ну а как быть с **третье** и др.?

Comment: Вам?   Уж и не знаю, как с вами быть? Выучите два правила)

Comment: Sharon: «_Вам? Уж и не знаю, как с вами быть? Выучите два правила)_» ===  Sharon, это Вы мне посоветовали?

Comment: А зачем вы дублируете мои комментарии? Любопытно, просто. Я не сотру их, не волнуйтесь. Можете поставить мне пару минусов, если правило вам не нравится.

Comment: Sharon: «_А зачем вы дублируете мои комментарии?_» === Просто для того, чтобы было понятно, на какой именно комментарий из приведённых выше я отвечаю.

Comment: У третье сколько буквенных окончаний? Одна буковка? Ее нельзя сокращать, а то ничего не останется.

Comment: Sharon: «_У третье сколько буквенных окончаний? Одна буковка? Ее нельзя сокращать, а то ничего не останется._» === Да, не останется. Но об этом в предложенной Вами формулировке правила НИЧЕГО не сказано.

Comment: Я считала, что это очевидно, извините.  Мы же сокращаем окончание, а не убираем совсем.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, ваше правило интересное и, возможно, чуть-чуть попроще, мэм. You should definitely spread it among your near and dear.

Comment: Благодарю вас. Не знаю, с кого начать...